# Bayesian probability with uncertain quality of evidence

Tags: statistics, probability

Suppose a Bayesian updater receives one of a finite number of signals. The device that gives him the signal is of uncertain quality. If it is high-quality the signal is always a perfect signal about some underlying variable he is interested in. If it is low-quality it is noise.

After seeing the signal he updates his beliefs about the underlying variable and the quality of the evidence device, right? But I am not sure how to model it.

I have tried looking at it 2 ways with very different answers.
a) He uses his updated belief about the quality of the device to form a posterior about the underlying variable, and his updated belief about the underlying variable to form a posterior about the quality of the device. This gives a system of equations with unique solutions for each one.
b) He forms a joint probability distribution over the two variables and updates it.

The former gives some weird results, such as if his prior beliefs about the distribution of signals from a high-quality and low-quality device, he updates his belief about the quality of the expert upwards, regardless of the signal.

The latter seems like it is imposing an independence assumption that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to think about the relations between variables. Everything else follows from that.

One model for an unreliable sensor is: `P(M | V, R) P(V) P(R)` where `M` is the measurement, `V` is the variable you are trying to measure, and `R` is the reliability of the sensor. These variables could be discrete or continuous, with `P(M | V, R)` being whatever makes sense for the problem at hand.

Operations on such a model could include computing `P(V | M)`, `P(R | M)`, and `P(V, R | M)`. Which of these is useful to you depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

I worked with models of unreliable sensors in Chapter 6 of my dissertation [1]. On looking at it again, it seems like Sections 6.3 and later are most relevant to you.

[1] http://riso.sourceforge.net/docs/dodier-dissertation.pdf